Flutter: Error "invalid source release: 17" when using connectivity_plus package
I'm encountering an error in my Flutter project when trying to compile with the connectivity_plus package. The error message I'm receiving is:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
> error: invalid source release: 17

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I tried:

flutter clean
set java_home

Current java version is 18.0.2.1

Earlier I was getting same error. I was using Android Studio (Electric Eel). When I went to 'Help -> About', I saw that the Runtime version was 11. This is what worked for me:

I downloaded latest Android Studio (Iguana) from this website: https://developer.android.com/studio
Now in Android Studio (Iguana), go to 'Help -> About' and the runtime version seen will be 17 as shown below: Runtime version is observed to be 17.0.9+ to be exact (this link contains the screenshot)

3. After this I just ran my flutter app through VS code and it worked! Hopefully the above solution works for you also :)

Yes, it worked perfectly for me. I too saw my Runtime version was 11. Downloaded the latest Android Studio and it worked like a charm on my VS Code.

what i should do for vs code ?
